# Getting objects.all() reverse() or descending order

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many, manytomanyfield, django-orm

In Django, calling `object.manytomany.all().reverse()`, and its template equivalent, `object.manytomany.all.reverse`, don't seem to work for many-to-many relationships.

How do I reverse a list of results of a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 6):

You may be going about this wrong or maybe I misunderstand your code snippet. Say you have a Book Model where an instance of a Book can have multiple authors.

```
class Author(models.Model):
  ...

class Book(models.Model):
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Now this will return a `QuerySet` of all Book instances - `Book.objects.all()`

`objects` is the default manager for a Model and it's plural. `object` is its own thing in Python and it's best not to use it as your own variable. It's also worth stating that "manytomany" isn't a field or function in Django. Let us know if that's something you defined. So to get the ManyToMany multiple authors a book instance might have:

```
book = Book.objects.all()[0]
type(book.authors)  # tells you this is a ManyRelatedManager
type(book.authors.all()) # tells you this is a QuerySet
book.authors.all()  # will print out the authors for this book
```

Now that you have the authors and those authors are in the form of a QuerySet, you can do any normal QuerySet manipulation including reversing.

```
book.authors.all().reverse()
```

Remember that reversing something that isn't ordered doesn't mean much so you may want to consider using `objects.order_by("<field name>").reverse()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of
objects.order_by("<field name>").reverse()
you can use
objects.order_by("-<field name>")
for descending order.

Comment: You can make a method for easy calling this queryset from the template. I.e. object.get_m2m_reversed, which inside calls self.manytomany.all().order_by('-somefield')

Answer (score 3):

So you can do it as

```
object.manytomany.order_by("-id")
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be used to order objects in the order we want according to their properties.

```
Doubt.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
```

Answer (score -2):

book = reversed(Book.objects.all())